# ListView not updating on adapter change

Tags: android, listview

When I scroll down the list after some time I get this error.
I have done this with `runOnUiThread()` in `doInBackground()`, but it's not working.
`ScrollListener` below:

```
listofcontests.setOnScrollListener(new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() {
    @Override
    public void onScroll(AbsListView view,
        int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount,
        int totalItemCount) {
        //Algorithm to check if the last item is visible or not
        final int lastItem = firstVisibleItem + visibleItemCount;
        final int totitem = Restotcnt-lastItem;
        if (lastItem == totalItemCount && totalItemCount != 0 && Restotcnt-lastItem >= totresults) {
            //if (totalItemCount - (firstVisibleItem + visibleItemCount) == SCROLL_OFFSET && totalItemCount != 0 && Restotcnt-lastItem >= totresults) {
            //                if (totalItemCount - (firstVisibleItem + 1 + visibleItemCount) < SCROLL_OFFSET &&
            //                        visibleItemCount < totalItemCount) {
            //                            // you have reached end of list, load more data
            totcount = lastItem + 1;
            limit = limit + totresults;
            new LoadContestList1(getApplicationContext()).execute();
            Log.d("limit=", limit + "-results=-" + totresults);
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
    }
});
```

`postExecute` Method:

```
protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
    if(flag){
        contestcout.setText(Restotcnt.toString());
        brandcout.setText(Rescntbusiness.toString());
        final contestListCustom adapter = new contestListCustom(MainActivityz.this, contestid, contestname, contestdescription, contestdateandtime, logo);
        listofcontests.setAdapter(adapter);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        listofcontests.setSelection(limit);
}
    else {
        //                flag =false;
        //                listofcontests.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        //                nodatafound = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvInternetAlert);
        //                nodatafound.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
}
```

Comment: can anyone please help me?

Comment: Post your error/logcat, specify your problem.

Comment: you said you are getting this error? but which error you didn't explain us @DaniyalTahir

Comment: i am getting this error:
The content of the adapter has changed but ListView did not receive a notification. Make sure the content of your adapter is not modified from a background thread, but only from the UI thread